How to implement tabs in Electron: Render offscreen WebContentsView
There is a new powerful feature WebContentsView, which allows to render multiple kinda BrowserWindow inside a single native window fully isolated.
It there a way of rendering them offscreen?
It looks like a perfect candidate for making tabs in an electron application.  For example like how VSCode does it with tabs. I believe tabs there have to be sort of isolated views (like iframe), otherwise the whole DOM tree will be too big and any updates could take ages.
